# How to fix VBA error message Run-time Error '1004' Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to make a column display desired statuses depending on the entries of 2 other columns.

Below are the codes.

Also, can anyone please explain to me what is the point of repeating those conditions in 2 codes `Sub compare2 ()` and `Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)`? This code is developed by an intern at my company. It makes sense to me for the use of the first but not the second code.

The `Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)` kept being highlighted by Excel for error message:

> Compile Error: Loop without Do, Else without If.

Then after that error, I got another on `Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)` with error:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Thanks!!!

```
Sub compare2()

Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16

Do While A <= 42
    i = 2
    Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

        If Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"

Else        

End If

i = i + 1

Loop

A = A + 4
B = A + 1
c = A + 2

Loop

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub single_change(changed_cell As Range)

    Dim sales_cell As Range
    Dim production_cell As Range
    Dim day_cell As Range

    If changed_cell.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Set sales_cell = changed_cell
        Set production_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, 1)
        Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        Set production_cell = changed_cell
        Set sales_cell = changed_cell.Offset(, -1)
        Set day_cell = production_cell.Offset(, 1)
    End If

    On Error GoTo multiple_changes

        If sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Green" Then
        day_cell = "Green"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Yellow" Then
        day_cell = "Yellow"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Red" Then
        day_cell = "Red"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Overdue" Then
        day_cell = "Overdue"

        ElseIf sales_cell = "Rollup" And production_cell = "Rollup" Then
        day_cell = "Rollup"
Else

End If

Exit Sub


multiple_changes:

Dim i As Long
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim c As Long

A = 14
B = 15
c = 16


Do While A <= 42
    i = 2
    Do Until Len(Cells(i, A)) = 0

        If Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Green" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Yellow" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Yellow"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Red" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Red"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Overdue" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Overdue"

        ElseIf Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" And Cells(i, B) = "Rollup" Then
        Cells(i, c) = "Rollup"
Else

End If

i = i + 1

Loop

    A = A + 4
    B = A + 1
    c = A + 2

Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you very very much!

Comment: properly [indent](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) and you will see you are missing an `End If`

Comment: or that the last `If` should be `ElseIf`

Comment: @ScottCraner Hi, can you please let me know where I should place the ```End If``` Thanks!!!

Comment: Your last `If` on the second code should be `ElseIf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for so many `If`s:

```
If Cells(i, A) = "Rollup" then
    Cells(i, c).value = Cells(i, B).value
End if
```

similarly:

```
If sales_cell = "Rollup" then
    day_cell.value = production_cell.value
End if
```

`Select case` may be a better option:

```
Select case sales_cell.value
    Case "Rollup"
        day_cell.value = production_cell.value
    Case "Green"
        if Production_cell.value  = "Overdue" then Cells(i, c).value = Production_cell.value  
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise but I believe can't use it this way since sometimes I have cases like Sales_cell=Green , Production_cell = Overdue then the status which is Cells(i, c) would be Overdue and it's case by case for these conditions

Comment: `Select Case` may be a better option. See edit to my answer,